# Add latency to domain

Tags: linux, ubuntu, proxy, latency

I have a question. Is it somehow possible to add latency to a Ubuntu server when it hits a specific domain?

For example it should add 50 ms for google.com

And add 20ms for Facebook.com

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with traffic shaping (which is not easily explained, `man tc`).

The qdiscs HFSC and netem offer the configuration of latency.

You need one class / qdisc for each of your categories and then you define a filter matching the target IPs which assigns those packets to the respective class / qdisc.